# Understanding MappingView ABC

Tags: python, python-3.x, abc

What is the difference between a MappingView container and a Sized container? Any examples on how to implement a MappingView container?

I might be misunderstanding ABCs and the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) entirely, but a MappingView container is  any container that inherits from Sized, right? If so, then why doesn't my dummy example work?

```
import collections

class MySized:
    def __len__():
        pass

class MyMappingView(MySized):
    pass

print(issubclass(MySized, collections.Sized)) # True
print(issubclass(MyMappingView, collections.MappingView)) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't subclass from it (virtually or otherwise). `MappingView` is used as a base class for the `keys/items/values` views. `Sized` is used for any object for which getting its size (`len`) makes sense.

These `ABC`s are used to check if certain objects in Python follow the interface they define. Instead of creating a custom `MappingView` you can just `register` any new classes that conform to it.

Suffice to say, you wouldn't `register` a class to `MappingView` since it used solely as a base class to provide a default `__len__`, `__repr__` and `__init__` to `Keys/Values/Items` views. If you have defined a new mapping type that returns custom views, simply register these views to the appropriate `Keys/Values/Items` views.